# python if elif different result

Tags: python, if-statement, quicksort, median

How can I find the median of the 1st, last and middle element and than swap the median with the 1st element?

Comment: Nobody is going to ignore the bad part. Please make sure that your question is precise and have only the relevant code posted here.

Comment: Would it help if i bold it, i feel people will get lost if they don't see the reference?

Comment: To be honest, most people will not be interested to go through a hugh chunk of code to understand what the real problem is.

Comment: +1 for the more succinct and detailed rewrite

Comment: The code is a pain to read; if you space the tokens you're more likely to receive an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you can do it like this:

```
from numpy import median

values    = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
med       = median([values[0], values[len(values)/2], values[-1]]) # calculate median of first, middle and last element in the list
values[0] = med # replace first element with median
```

Which results in:

```
>>> med
4.0
>>> values
[4.0,2,3,4,5,6]
```

This answers your question as written, but I'm not sure it's exactly what you want. You might try re-wording your question to make it a bit more clear exactly what you want the final output list to look like.

**Update**

As described in the comments, it appears swapping the value in the list equal to the median with the first element is the desired output. In that case, try the following:

```
halfway_idx = len(values)/2
med         = median([values[0], values[halfway_idx], values[-1]])
if med == values[0]:
   pass # median already is in the first position
elif med == values[halfway_idx]:
   values[0], values[halfway_idx] = values[halfway_idx], values[0] #swap middle and first
else:
   values[0], values[-1] = values[-1], values[0] # swap first and last
```

Comment: Well I need them to swap. so 1st element comes to the medians position and median to the 1st place.
Sry for late response, was installing numpy :D